# Should I use both OneHotEncoder and OrdinalEncoder in one dataset?

Tags: data-science, data-analysis, one-hot-encoding, data-preprocessing

if a dataset contains both nominal and ordinal columns, is the dataset need different encoders like OneHotEncoder for nominal and OrdinalEncoder for ordinal values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, categorical/nominal and numeric (including ordinal) variables need to be treated differently, and it is very.common to encounter datasets with several types of variables.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. I have one more question, if I choose the easy way by applying LabelHotEncoder to both ordinal and nominal values, will there be any problem?

Comment: That would not respect the ordering of the ordinal variables.

Comment: I mean, regression algorithms will have problems, but classifier algorithms will not be a problem?

Comment: Both will have "problems"